# How to Copy Data to Blank Line then Delete Original in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty coding in excel and can't figure out how to do everything I need to.  I'm trying to take data from one row, search for a blank row in a different area of the same sheet on the same workbook, copy the data using the values-only setting, then delete the original data.

Here's what I have so far, the only problem is I'm unsure how to tell it to paste the data.  The question marks indicate where I'm stuck.  Do I even need something else or can I just go straight to the 'selection.pastespecial' part of the code?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
   Sub Find_Blank_And_Fill()
    Dim cnter As Integer

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cnter = 0

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Range("B29:F29").Select
            Selection.copy
            ????
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            End Select
            cnter = cnter + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

There's a photo to help make this easier to understand if I'm not conveying it well.

[image: Visual Description]

Sincerely,

ProWHP

Answer (score 0):

What you've got already will work.  However, I would make these edits:

```
Sub Find_Blank_And_Fill()
Dim cnter As Integer

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cnter = 0
Range("B29:F29").copy 'Avoid using "Select"! Also, this way you only copy once.

For i = 3 To lastRow 'Start your fill operation after your known rows
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Cells(i,2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Simplified
        cnter = cnter + 1 'Why is this here?  It's counting empty rows right now
    End If
Next i
application.cutcopymode = false 'Turns off the box around the area you copied
End Sub
```